# What does #pragma comment(lib, "XXX") actually do with "XXX"?

Tags: c++, pragma

I have to maintain some legacy (MS) C++. In that codebase, I stumbled across:

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "OtherLib700.lib")
```

Where 700 is some versioning. Besides, the lib is a DLL with the same name.

I first thought that the program would be dependent upon the DLL, but after removing it from the system, the program still works. There exists a newer version of the DLL, though, which is named OtherLib900.

It seems as though the program 'included' the code of the lib so that it's no longer dependent upon the external DLL. (Or that the program 'automatically' uses the newer DLL.)

Which one is correct? Is there are way to further confirm that 'assumption'?

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib...` (etc) is usually a bad solution. It's tool-chain/platform dependent and is better handled by your (meta)build system like `cmake`, `make`, `scons`, `msbuild`, `qmake` or whatnot - that stuff doesn't belong embedded in source files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a program has this pragma it will look for the library `OtherLib700.lib`. If that is an import library when the program is loaded windows will search for `OtherLib700.dll` in the path. It will not try to look for `OtherLib900.dll` during execution so it must be finding your `dll` in a different folder. This assumes that `OtherLib700.lib` is an import library and not a static library. If OtherLib700.lib is a static library then that is all it needs.

The documentation for `#pragma comment( lib libname)` states the following:

> Places a library-search record in the object file. This comment type
> must be accompanied by a comment-string parameter that has the name
> (and possibly the path) of the library that you want the linker to
> search. The library name follows the default library-search records in
> the object file. The linker searches for this library the same way as
> if you specified it on the command line, as long as the library isn't
> specified by using /nodefaultlib. You can place multiple
> library-search records in the same source file. Each record appears in
> the object file in the same order it's found in the source file.

Answer (score 81):

That `pragma` is used to link against the specified `.lib` file. This is an alternative to specifying the library in the external dependencies field in project settings.

Mostly, it's used to support different versions:

```
#ifdef USE_FIRST_VERSION
#pragma comment(lib, "vers1.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "vers2.lib")
#endif
```

When your application uses a dynamically-linked library, a `lib` file tells you information about what symbols are exported in the `dll`. So basically you only need the `lib` to compile & link, but you need the `dll` to run the program, as it contains all the binary code.

You say there's an associated `dll`, which usually indicates the `lib` file only contains linking info, and no code. You should get a run-time error if the associated `dll` was not found. You can check with MSVS if a different version of the `dll` was loaded or if it was loaded from a different place.

Comment: *"You only need the lib to compile & link"* .. so the lib can be like an alternative to a header file (.h)?

Comment: @Acidic I think what Luchian means is that the `dll` won't be necessary in that case. You'll find that the header file still is.

Comment: Where can we put it though? Is it fine if we add it in main.cpp or can we include it anywhere (only once)?

Answer (score -2):

If the .lib is a "real" lib with the actual code (I've never used DLLs save for the system-provided ones, but I believe you make 'import libs' for your own DLLs), then the DLL isn't required.

As for the subject, #pragma comment(lib,xxx) allows programs to add certain options for the linker. Can be very useful, although I've missed a few options that I would have liked to add like this. The example given is a prime example for its use: when the object file is included in the program, then the lib specified will be added as well.

Comment: I think he meant "static" library.

Comment: @moala irrelevant. Technically they are the same and hybrid libraries exist (i.e. combining import stubs and other symbols which would typically live in static libraries).